# nginx autostarted after shutdown with systemctl

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, systemd

I'm running Linux Mint 19.2 Tina, which should be equivalent to Ubuntu 18.04.

When I issue the command sudo `systemctl stop nginx.service` then `systemctl start nginx.service` I frequently get the error

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and

```
nginx: [error] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I'm not able to restart nginx with the systemctl command, but checking with `ps aux | grep nginx` shows that nginx is running. Checking with `sudo ss -lnp | grep nginx` shows that the process is bound to port 80 and port 443. But `/run/nginx.pid` does not exist.

I can kill this process manually with `sudo kill $PID_OF_MASTER_NGINX_PROCESS` but the normal control commands don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I finally noticed something that helped solve this. When I examined the output of `ps aux | grep nginx` after starting with systemctl, I saw something like the following...

```
$ ps aux | grep nginx
root     30369  0.0  0.0 142168  2004 ?        Ss   21:31   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data 30370  0.0  0.1 144464  6840 ?        S    21:31   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 30371  0.0  0.1 144464  6840 ?        S    21:31   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 30372  0.0  0.1 144464  6840 ?        S    21:31   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 30373  0.0  0.1 144464  6840 ?        S    21:31   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

But after the process autostarted on me I saw the following...

```
$ ps aux | grep nginx
root     29591  0.0  0.1 142732  9440 ?        Ss   21:25   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
www-data 29616  0.0  0.1 145028  7248 ?        S    21:25   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 29617  0.0  0.1 145028  7248 ?        S    21:25   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 29618  0.0  0.1 145028  7248 ?        S    21:25   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 29619  0.0  0.1 145028  7248 ?        S    21:25   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

Notice that the command line options for the master process were a bit different. In the systemctl case the command line options included `-g daemon on; master_process on;` but in the other case they included `-c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. Two different processes were trying to control nginx. The second one would notice that it wasn't running and try to autostart it.

The command line with `-g daemon on; master_process on;` was reflected in the systemd file `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`. The other command line was reflected in `/etc/init.d/nginx`. I guessed that both systemd and the old init system were trying to run nginx.

I ran the command `sudo update-rc.d -f nginx disable` which removed the nginx start scripts from all the run level directories for the old init system. Now nginx starts and stops properly with the systemctl commands.

Comment: Thanks ! I also noticed the params but didn't knew what to do next. I also had to add `--standalone` because nginx plugin in certbot was running somehow. See this topic: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/702133/how-does-certbot-bind-port-could-not-bind-tcp-port-80-because-it-is-already-in